# Passing callbacks in Typescript - why can the callback's argument not match and compile?

Tags: typescript

I have a contrived example that was derived from a React callback that I was making.

```
interface A {
    a: string
    b: string
}

interface B {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
}

function foo(fn: (a: A) => void, a: A) {
    fn(a)
}

function bar(arg: B): void {
    console.log(arg.c)
}

foo(bar, {a: 'a', b: 'b'}) // This works, unfortunately
```

Here, `bar` is a valid argument to `foo`, even though `bar`'s first argument has more fields than the one that `foo` says it should have. That means that someone who supplies `bar` as a callback here would think that they're going to have a `c` `string` in their argument, but they won't.

It's not like there is no type checking on the arguments. The following correctly fails:

```
function baz(arg: string) { }

foo(baz, {a: 'a', b: 'b'}) // This fails correctly
```

What exactly is going on here and is there a way of specifying the types such that the behavior is closer to what would be ideal?

Comment: Which TypeScript version are you using?

Comment: Using version 2.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a good use case for generics. You want to make sure that the type passed in as the argument is compatible with the function parameter. If these are the same generic parameter, the compiler should check that they are consistent.

```
interface A {
    a: string
    b: string
}

interface B {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
}

function foo<T extends A>(fn: (a: T) => void, a: T & {}) {
    fn(a)
}

function bar(arg: B): void {
    console.log(arg.c)
}

foo(bar, {a: 'a', b: 'b'}) //error
```

Notice that the `a` parameter of `foo` is typed as `T&{}` not just `T`. This is done to decrease the priory of that inference site. Since `T` can be infered from either `fn` or `a` we want to make sure the compiler favors `fn` even if it could pick a type for `T` that would make both parameters compatible (in this case that type would be `A`). I don't remember where I found this behavior documented but I'm sure a member of the compiler team said it can be relied upon for the foreseeable future :-)

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately the error is on the object and not the function. It's very close to what I want but you're actually exposing the error of my snippet creation process. It doesn't actually reflect the original problem I had it seems. That said, I didn't know about this so that's great.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very interesting, I think this would explain why it works, unfortunately not how to disallow a similar situation... :(

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks like there is a section in there that describes this behavior specifically: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance. I'd like to hold out for some creative alternatives before accepting though.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a **contract** that requires a structure to provide certain attributes (or behavior). That is true for any language that supports the concept of interfaces.

Look at this example:

```
class C implements A, B {
  a: string
  b: string
  c: string    
}
```

The type `C` conforms to both `A` and `B`. Consequently you should be able to use instances of `C` wherever either `A` or `B` is required. It would be weird if you couldn't.

If you apply for a job that requires a degree in computer science then you are qualified even if you have additional degrees. You would find it disturbing if they rejected you for no other reason than having additional skills.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue fully. Its worth mentioning that the analogy does not hold if we're talking about object literals. There, if you supply a "masters degree" instead of a bachelors then you do get rejected: `const a: A = {a: '', b: '', c: ''}` gets rejected despite having it work if the type were passed. That's really the behavior I want for the types. I understand that this is how structural typing is working, but I'm interested in alternative approaches to achieve this.

Also, `bar` requires a masters degree but its being given a bachelors.

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo You are right, TypeScript is restrictive when it comes to object literals. It's debatable whether that's good or bad, but it has not always been that way. You can read the arguments of the language creator himself  [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755)